# Is it possible to integrate CiviCRM with a hosted VOIP solution?

Tags: api, civicrm-entity, phone

My company may be moving to a hosted VOIP solution.  I've been looking for a solution to integrate a VOIP system with CiviCRM but it appears that this is still under development and no solution is in place at this time.  Is it possible to integrate a VOIP system with CiviCRM?  I'm looking to automate creation of an activity and update fields with call data.  I assume a browser plugin could handle the click to dial portion but Im unsure.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @joemurray has extensions for outgoing VoIP.  I recently referred a client with your same need to Fuzion, so they may be working on incoming VoIP.

Comment: We also have outgoing through Twilio, and have been toying with the idea of developing something for incoming for a while, so could be wrestled in finally doing it with a little funding..

Comment: I think that Circle Interactive in Bristol have something that integrates Civi with a phone system, but don't know the details.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a single unified VOIP interface, so each interface with civi would have to be custom.

I've seen two interfaces with an Asterisk based VOIP:
- fetch the name of the caller (based on the number) to display it on the phone when ringing
- add click to call on various screen (at least the contact details)
- log a call

For the last one, I don't think it has never been very useful, because most of the callers don't seem to think most of the calls are important enough

Neither of these were hard to develop, but as said, it's probably quite specific to what is your VOIP solution.