# Integrating CiviCRM with phone management software

Tags: integration

Has anyone tried to integrate CiviCRM with a phone management system (probably but not necessarily VOIP)? We know this is possible technically speaking but are very interested in experiences and stories...

Comment: Not the same, but on a related note, for anyone interested in phone numbers, there is a rather nifty phone number validator :)

Comment: I think I recollect from some years back that CircleInteractive saying that they did this...

Comment: Duplicate of this? http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/12062/49

Comment: Not if I do not want to use VOIP :-)